# Pandas sample from df keeping balance of groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, sample

Lets generate some dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
categs = ['cat1'] * 600 + ['cat2'] * 300 + ['cat3'] * 100
subcats = ['sub1', 'sub2', 'sub2', 'sub3', 'sub3', 'sub4', 'sub4', 'sub4', 'sub4', 'sub4'] * 100
subcats[0] = 'subX'
vals = range(1000)
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'category': categs,
   'subcategory': subcats,
   'values': vals
})
```

So let's look at amount of rows by category and subcategory:

```
print(df.groupby(['category', 'subcategory']).size())
```

we got

```
>>>
category  subcategory
cat1      sub1            59
          sub2           120
          sub3           120
          sub4           300
          subX             1
cat2      sub1            30
          sub2            60
          sub3            60
          sub4           150
cat3      sub1            10
          sub2            20
          sub3            20
          sub4            50
dtype: int64
```

This is a dataframe of 1000 elements. There are 600 elements of cat1, 300 of cat2 and 100 of cat3. What I want is to reduce this dataframe from 1000 to let's say 60 rows so
1)**each category has same amount of rows** (20 in our case, which equals *60 / (number of categories)*)
2) proportion of each subcategory in a category is kept
3) **if we have small number of subcategory items it still stays in category** (there is only one 'subX' in cat1, we need to keep it even if it's proportion was 1/600 for cat1).

So when we create our new df I would like to receive something like this:

```
print(newdf.groupby(['category', 'subcategory']).size())


category  subcategory
cat1      sub1            2
          sub2           4
          sub3           4
          sub4           10
          subX             1
cat2      sub1            2
          sub2            4
          sub3            4
          sub4           10
cat3      sub1            2
          sub2            4
          sub3            4
          sub4            10
dtype: int64
```

In this case there are 21 element for cat1, but it is not a big deal, the main idea is that proportion of subcategories are saved and amount of rows is around targeted number 20.

Comment: You want random 6% per group, or for example first 6% per group?

Comment: Random, not first. And it won't be 6% per group, each category needs to have same amount of elements. So for cat1 it will be 3,33%, for cat2 it will be 5,55% and for cat3 it will be 20%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the number of rows that you should keep per subcategory, and keep only the rows with `cumcount` below that number:

```
# total (approximate) number of rows to keep
n = 60

# number of rows per category
n_per_cat = n / df['category'].nunique()

# number of rows per subcategory
g_subcat = df.groupby(['category', 'subcategory'])
z = g_subcat['category'].size()
n_per_subcat = np.ceil(z / z.sum(level=0) * n_per_cat)

# output
df_out = (df
          .assign(i=g_subcat.cumcount())
          .merge(n_per_subcat.rename('n').reset_index())
          .query('i < n')
          .drop(columns=['i', 'n']))

# test
df_out.groupby(['category', 'subcategory']).size()
```

Output:

```
category  subcategory
cat1      sub1            2
          sub2            4
          sub3            4
          sub4           10
          subX            1
cat2      sub1            2
          sub2            4
          sub3            4
          sub4           10
cat3      sub1            2
          sub2            4
          sub3            4
          sub4           10
```

P.S. And to make it random, you can, of course, shuffle the dataframe before all this with:

```
df = df.sample(frac=1)
```